# flutter web showing 404 error when hash removed

Tags: flutter, dart, url, hash

I have done a webpage with flutter. I have removed the hash symbol from url using `setPathUrlStrategy()` method. But after hosting to the server the hash is removed from the url but when the page is refreshed it shows 404 error page. I have found different solution like changing the `<base href='/'>` in index.html to `<base href='./'>` but done these all solution but not working. I have also tried creating a `404 and .htaccess` file and put it in the same level of index.html in web folder of flutter this too doesnt work.

i am use **Nginx web server** and sample of my web url is as  `example.demo.com`

the sample of my .htaccess file is as below:

````
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

If anyone has any idea please help
````